# javascript/jquery: How to prevent from continuing to fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my example code/jsfiddle:  If you move your mouse back and forth quickly over the word testing to where your mouse leaves the div(#footer_logo_container), hovers the div, leaves the div, etc.....it is like the script counts how many times your mouse goes over it, and the div(#powered_by) fades in/fades out/fades in/fades out over and over again depending on how many times your mouse went over the div.

**Question:**  Is there a way to make it that when the mouse goes over the #footer_logo_container, the #powered_by div appears.  I also would like to find out if there is a way to have it so it stays faded in for a minimum amount of time (x seconds) once the mouse moves off #footer_logo_container where if the mouse continues to go in and out of the text, it ignores it until the #powered_by is completely faded out.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5jEmc/1/

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#footer_logo_container").hover( 
        function() { $(this).find("#powered_by").fadeIn(); },
        function() { $(this).find("#powered_by").fadeOut(); }
        );         
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer_logo_container">
    Testing<br /><br /><br />
    <div id="powered_by">FadeIn</div>
</div>
```

CSS: `#powered_by { display: none; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `stop()` [See more](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/5jEmc/2/)**

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#footer_logo_container").hover( 
        function() { $(this).find("#powered_by").stop().fadeIn(); },
        function() { $(this).find("#powered_by").stop().fadeOut(); }
        );         
});
```

If you want `delay` before executing `fadeOut`, use this line.

```
function() { $(this).find("#powered_by").stop()delay(1000).fadeOut(); }
```

Comment: is there a way to add a minimum time it stays faded in before the fadeout function starts? (lets say, 5 seconds)

Comment: use `.stop().delay(1000)` for fadeOut

Comment: modified the code to do exactly what I wanted.  Added stop and delay in the fade in, and just used delay on the fadeout.  `$(this).find("#powered_by").stop().fadeIn('slow').delay(1000); },
 function() { $(this).find("#powered_by").fadeOut().delay(1000); } );`

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#footer_logo_container").hover( 
        function(event) { $(this).find("#powered_by").fadeIn(); 
                   event.stopImmediatePropagation()},
        function(event) {  
            $(this).find("#powered_by").fadeOut();                    
                   event.stopImmediatePropagation()}
        );         
});
```

Comment: can you explain what this does exactly?  I've never used event.stopImmediatePropagation() before.

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` will not prevent that described effect. The effect is because jQuery uses animation queuing, so without using `stop` or `clearQueue` the `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` are appended to the queue for each move in and move out. If that happens fast you have a queue like `fadeIn -> fadeOut -> fadeIn -> fadeOut -> ...`